# Map all item in array with headlessui tabs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, headless

I want to display all items in the following array on all tabs.

I'm able to show items by category but I can't think of an additional way to show all items on all tabs.

> This is what I expected.

[image]

```
export default function ServicetList() {
    const [tabs] = useState({
        NAS: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "DSM",
            href: "#",
            category: "NAS",
          },
        ],
        Email: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Webmail",
            href: "#",
            category: "Email",
          },
    });
return (
    <div>
        <Tab.Group>
            <Tab.List>
                {Object.keys(tabs).map((category) => (<Tab key={category}>{category}</Tab>))}
            </Tab.List>
            <Tab.Panels>
                {Object.values(tabs).map((services, idx) => (
                    <Tab.Panel key={idx}>
                        <ul role="list">
                            {services.map((service) => (
                              <li key={service.id}><h3>{service.name}</h3></li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </Tab.Panel>
                ))}
            </Tab.Panels>
        </Tab.Group>
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to just add one more tab manually with 'All'.

```
<Tab.List>
  <Tab key='all'>All</Tab>
  {Object.keys(tabs).map((category) => (<Tab key={category}>{category}</Tab>))}
</Tab.List>
<Tab.Panels>
  <Tab.Panel key='all'>
      {Object.values(tabs).map((services, idx) => (
      <ul role="list">
        {services.map((service) => (
          <li key={service.id}><h3>{service.name}</h3></li>
        ))}
      </ul>
  ))}
  </Tab.Panel>
  {Object.values(tabs).map((services, idx) => (
    <Tab.Panel key={idx}>
      <ul role="list">
        {services.map((service) => (
          <li key={service.id}><h3>{service.name}</h3></li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Tab.Panel>
  ))}
</Tab.Panels>
```